# Dynamically adding scripts removed automatically from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been adding some scripts by script tag dynamically using jquery but the added script tags removed automatically within few seconds(on full load of the page).

```
<script async src="/Site/WebResource.axd?d=syVws_Iy..."></script>
<script async src="/Site/GetResource.ashx?..."></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("hi");
</script>
```

From another website running in IIS, I am getting the scripts using ajax call in js file through url for a page, here using Regex to finding the script tags from that response and adding to head tag

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    kenticositeResponse();
    $(window).error(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
function kenticositeResponse() {
    var protocol = "http://IP/";
    var server = "Site/";
    var accessPage = "Home.aspx";
    var url = protocol + server + accessPage;
    res = "";
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        options.async = true;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (result) {
            res = result;
            var str = res;            

            var scrpt = /<(?:SCRIPT|script \b[^>]*)>([\s\S]*?)<\/(?:SCRIPT|script)>/gm;
            while (res1 = scrpt.exec(str)) {
                $("head").append(res1[0]);
            }
    }
}).done(function () {

});
```

}

Can anyone help me, what causes the issue here?

Comment: Added dynamically how? You're not showing the logic that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Jaw.sh: I have updated for the logic which i'm using

Comment: Isn't that what your script is doing? Moving them from their existing location, and adding to the bottom of the `<head>`? So they will disappear from their original location.

Comment: @Akurn: I am not moving, I'm finding the script tags from another page and loading to head tag of current page.

Comment: Ah I see. You're better off showing a more complete example then, what you have here could be anything.